# Is there any comprehensive book that reviews topics in the area of brain-inspired computing?

Tags: reference-request, neuromorphic-engineering, books, neuroscience, human-inspired

I am looking to write my master's thesis next year about brain-inspired computing. Hence, I am looking to get a good overview of this domain.

Do you know of any comprehensive book that reviews topics in the area of brain-inspired computing (such as spiking neural networks)?

In spirit and scope, it should be similar to Ian Goodfellow's book deep learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular theoretical framework in use currently, in the neuromorphic (brain-inspired) computing community is the Neural Engineering Framework (NEF). Neural Engineering by Chris Eliasmith and Charles Anderson explains the framework comprehensively.

As a follow up to that, How to Build a Brain by Chris Eliasmith describes the more recent and more high-level description of how to get spiking neural networks to actually perform multiple functions: the Semantic Pointer Architecture (SPA).

If you're looking for hardware descriptions too, the research publications on the chips Neurogrid, Brainscales, Braindrop, SpiNNaker, Loihi, TrueNorth etc. provide some good high-level descriptions of how to actually build the aforementioned chips.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Artificial Intelligence SE. Thanks for trying to contribute to our site! It may be a good idea to provide links to the cited books or their pdfs, if available.